# MVC INSERT INTO Stuck with Where to go from here

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, view

**I have a model** register.php (under app/model/register.php)

```
<?PHP

// Load the [default] db group
$this->load->database();

// Get Input from init form, sanitize, plop into variables.
class Register extends Model{

    function formModel(){
    //load parent constructor
    parent::Model();
    }

    function sanitizeInput(){
        var $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fullname']);
        var $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        var $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        var $dySalt = mt_rand(20,100); 
        var $pass = hash('sha512',$dySalt.$pass);
    }

    // Set form variables into object; define db table
    $registeredObject = new getSanitizeNewRegistrant();
    $tbl = 'Fan';

    function SendRequestForData(){
        if{
        $this->db->insert($tbl,$object);
        // .. redirect()
        echo "Sent";
        }
        else{
        echo "Oops, could not register you";
        }
    }



}
?>
```

**I'm loading this model into a controller registerUsers.php** (under app/controller/registerUsers.php)

```
<?PHP


$this->load->model('register'),'', TRUE);


?>
```

I'm confused how I go about implementing this in a `view` from here?

Comment: After looking into your code i suggest you to go through the codeigniter user guide and clear your basic concept

Comment: Please see updated model. Can you help me now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC framework works as follows:

**Model interacts with the database:**
Here is where you want to put all of your functions that do nothing more than insert and return data to/from the database.

**Views are what the user sees:**
Here is where you'll have your html pages that make use of the data you got through your model

**Controllers simply connect the two:**
The controller preps data, uses the model to interact with the database, and loads the views for the user to see

If you had a function `registerUser()` in your register model, you would do something like this to actually use it within a function in the controller:

```
$this->load->model( 'register' ); // Load register model
$return = $this->register->registerUser( $_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'] ); // Try to register the user to the database
if( $return === "TRUE" ) {
  $this->load->view( 'success' ); // Hooray!
}
else {
  $this->load->view( 'fail' ); // :(
}
```

Here, the controller loads the register model, tries to save the username, email and password using the `registerUser()` function within the model, and loads the correct view accordingly.

Obviously you'll want to clean `$_POST` data and everything before writing it to the database. This should be done within the controller.